# pick cards (fewer cards ,cost less) - performance issue

Tags: python

n - number of cards in hand eg : `n = 4`

collection - cards collection as per n eg: collection =[1,3,4,7]

d denotes total cards eg: 10 `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Card 1-cost 1 ; card 5-cost 5

Scenario  : need to pick cards not in the collection list and the card cost less than (d) and maximum no of possible cards need to show

```
eg: sum of (2+5) <10 so we need to show (fewer cards ,cost less) accepted
eg: sum of (2+6) < 10 rejected (fewer cards ,cost more) 
eg: sum of (2+5+6) < 10 rejected (more cards ,cost more,count more than d) 
eg: sum of  (2+8) < 10 rejected (cost more)
```

it working fine for small data getting performance issue:

Scenario 1:

```
start = time. time()
n=4
collection=[1,3,4,7]
d=10
lis=[]
list1=[]
[lis.append(x+1) for x in range(0,d)]
[lis.remove(x) for x in collection]  
#print(lis)
#for L in range(0, len(lis)+1):
for subset in itertools.combinations(lis, d%n):
    if sum(subset)<=d:
        #print(subset)
        list1.append(subset)
k = list(map(lambda x: len(x),list1))
s = list(filter (lambda x: len(x)==max(k),list1))
m = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == min(list(map(lambda x: sum(x),s))),s))
print(*m[0],sep='\n')
end = time. time()
print(end - start)
```

Result:
2 5
time 0.0

scenario 2 :  **n=8    collection=[1,3,4,7,20,25,50,60]    d=100**

Result
2
5
6
8

Time:762.9762706756592

Comment: It might make sense to directly find the subsets those sum is less than or equal to d rather than using combinations as those can be computed without rejections.

Comment: Can you explain scenario 2? If the sum of picked cards must be less than 100, you can still add several cards to the result.

Comment: Scenario 2: he must select the lesser cost in combination  (2+5+6+8)= 21<100 accepted (fewer cards ,cost less) and (2+5+6+9) =22< 100 rejected (fewer cards ,cost more)

Comment: @Vinoth96 But why can't you keep adding more cards as long as you are under 100? E.g. `2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14` would sum 90, isn't 10 cards better than 4?

Comment: Yes it correct.. we can show the as listed the combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think this does something like what you want:

```
def pick_cards(collection, d):
    collection_set = set(collection)
    # The ordered sequence of cards not in collection
    pickable = (i for i in range(1, d + 1) if i not in collection_set)
    # Sum of picked cards
    s = 0
    # Picked cards
    picked = []
    for pick in pickable:
        # If the card does not go over the limit
        if s + pick < d:
            # Add card
            picked.append(pick)
            s += pick
        else:
            # Otherwise finish
            break
    return picked

# Examples
print(pick_cards([1, 3, 4, 7], 10))
# [2, 5]
print(pick_cards([1, 3, 4, 7, 20, 25, 50, 60], 100))
# [2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```